# python のシングルクォートとダブルクォート、どちらを利用するかの規約について

Tags: python

python においては、`'文字列'`と`"文字列"`のように、文字列リテラルを記述するにあたってはシングルクォート`'`を使うかダブルクォート`"`を使うかの選択肢があります。

#### 質問

python の文字列リテラルに対して、シングルクォートを使うべきか、ダブルクォートを使うべきかについての規約はありますか？

それとも、だいたいの場合において、どちらか好きな方をプログラマが選んで利用すればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PEP-8 に記述](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes)があります。

> This PEP does not make a recommendation for this. Pick a rule and stick to it. When a string contains single or double quote characters, however, use the other one to avoid backslashes in the string. It improves readability.

つまり、どちらが良いということはないけど、どちらかを選んでそれを統一的に使いましょう、ということですね。[Google Python Style Guide でも同様](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md#310-strings)に書いてあります。